# How to display progress of the file upload using node.js in real time

Tags: node.js

I am working on the project which simply read the txt/csv files from the directory and store in the database.

The upload function works like a charm but the problem is that I want to display the progress - any notification that tells the users that the system is working on the files.

Here is my HTML markup

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" />
    <button id="submit" type="button">Upload</button>
</div>
<div class="terminal">
<! -------------------RESULT---------------------->
</div>
```

I have the div called terminal to display the progress of file uploading. The way I place text inside the div is to use the innerHTML function of javascript. Thus, my upload code is as follows

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(folder_path);

// Loop through files gathered from folder reading

for(i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    document.getElementbyId("terminal").innerHTML+=files[i]+"<br/>";
    var fileData = fs.readfileSync(folder_path+'\'+files[i], 'utf8');
    // Upload function below
}
```

The above markup is a part of my js file which serves as an uploader. I first read the folder with fs.readdirSync, then iterate through the array of files gathered from readdirSync function. I want to display the file name in each loop in real time.

But it just displays everything once the upload has finished. So I don't know how to make it display the progress in real time or in other word, just like the console which displays any information in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop, you can easily port this to your frontend app:

**Monitoring XHR Progress**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress